# Best way to keep the image ratio, while it is responsive and gets a min-height

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to keep the `<img />` ratio while it is responsive and gets a min-height?

**What I want** is to set a `min-height` when `screen-size is lower than 620px` and the picture has to be horizontally centered while not loosing the ratio.

See my code and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M2Qkh/

```
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3484/3718426345_6d4a540840_b.jpg" />
<style type="text/css">
img {
    width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    img {
        display:block;
        min-height:150px;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: add [`width: auto`](http://jsfiddle.net/FV85a/1/)?

Comment: @Yoshi Thank you, but no: (http://jsfiddle.net/M2Qkh/1/)

Comment: So what is it that you want? You can't have two fixed dimensions and still want the image to scale itself proportionally. There is a conflict in the requirements.

Comment: Yoshi is right. If you want to keep image ratio, and at the same time keep one of the dimensions fixed, then your image just will not be responsive.

Comment: @Yoshi I like this http://jsfiddle.net/M2Qkh/4/ as I don't know how to write the title or question better but this is what I mean. That somewhen I need to give a min-height and the picture has to be centered while not loosing the ratio. I've tried things like margin:0 auto; but thats not "pushing" the img in minus position..

Comment: @caramba It is. I just didn't *get* what you wanted from how the question was written. But you have your answer, so all is good.

Comment: @Yoshi thank you! I updated the answer for all the other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to make it a background image, then apply the css to the container div or span:

```
.carousel-img {
    background-image:url(http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3484/3718426345_6d4a540840_b.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    max-width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center 20%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    display: block;
}
```

Note the background-position is in the center and 20% more to the top.

Also note the important background-size to be 'cover'.

The cover effect will some what cover the hole width space, and some how reserve its ratio (off course you will lose some of the left and right edges of the width, but thats the trade-off maintaining the ratio).

**Edit:**
a fiddle  created by the OP to illustrate both effects:
http://jsfiddle.net/M2Qkh/4/

Answer (score 2):

At media-query min-width 620px, you are now essentially setting both the height and the width of the image which is going to cause it to change 'ratio'.

Once the min-height: 150px takes effect then the image will start to squash as you have the width set to 100%.

If you don't want this to happen you need to change the image width in the media-query to `width: auto;` this will tell it to maintain the correct aspect ration whilst having a height set to 150px. As a result the image will start to be cropped (overflowing the container) rather than squashed. If this is the effect you want you will need a couple of other changes as well.  You will also need to set an `overflow: hidden;` on a container for the image, otherwise you will get a horizontal scrollbar.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    img {
        display:block;
        height:150px; /* use height not min-height */
        width: auto;
    }
    .img-wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
}
```

Comment: thank you (+1) also added margin:0 auto; to center but the image is not completely centered; http://jsfiddle.net/M2Qkh/7/

Comment: even if you added the margin, it will only center the image if the width of the container is larger than the width of the image (which in most cases is not). so this is will not scale. it will only cut the right side of the image without centering.

Comment: I think of you want the image to crop from both sides you will have to set it as a background image and then set background-position: 50% 50%;